# How to Display 'Loading...' image before rendering on ajax calls

Tags: ajax, richfaces

I have written this code

```
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="second,third" immediate="true" />
```

I want to display a progreess bar or 'Loading...' image while we are getting the response from server.

Is there a component availble that will allow us to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A component already exists within the a4j library.  Use the `<a4j:status>` component.  Say you're loader (animated gif) is called `ai.gif`, then your code would look like this.

```xml
<a4j:status>
    <f:facet name="start">
        <h:graphicImage value="/images/ai.gif" alt="ai" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="stop">
        <!-- no image; successfully loaded, or could display a checkmark or something -->
    </f:facet>
</a4j:status>
```

---

#### See Also

- [RichFaces Showcase - Ajax Output/Containers](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=status&sample=viewUsage&skin=blueSky)
- [RichFaces Dev Guide - JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_status.html)

Comment: But this can be implemented outside the form.And is applicable for any ajax request in form.Need to display this for one component.

Comment: @Shayan you can put a name on your `<a4j:status>` component and reference it using `<f:ajax status="thename">`.  It is also possible to not have it rendered once you don't want it anymore.